# setLookAndFeel and NullPointerException

Tags: swing, clojure

Has anyone ever tried to change swing's look and feel? This code, taken from an example, simply yields a null pointer exception, and I wonder what might be wrong:

```
(javax.swing.UIManager/setLookAndFeel 
  (javax.swing.UIManager/getSystemLookAndFeelClassName))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works here.  What does `(javax.swing.UIManager/getSystemLookAndFeelClassName)` return?

Comment: It returns "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"

Comment: NPE must almost certainly come from somewhere else. public static void setLookAndFeel(String className)
                           throws ClassNotFoundException,
                                  InstantiationException,
                                  IllegalAccessException,
                                  UnsupportedLookAndFeelException

Are you running this example exactly as is above from a fresh REPL? Only other suggestion is list your JRE details.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(prn "LAFs:" (map #(.toString %) 
  (javax.swing.UIManager/getInstalledLookAndFeels)))
```

to get a list of installed L&Fs; then you can hand-pick one you like.

Not a complete solution (I agree with Brian that your code Should Simply Work™) but this should at least give you some options.